# Show labels in stacked bar chart with Ng2Charts

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

i have an Anuglar6 project with a stacked bar chart actually build with Ng2Charts.
Is it possible to show the values within each sections of one stack ?

And if not, does anyone know a angular2 module which make this possible ?

[image: This is what i want]

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script data-require="chart.js@2.6.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <app-root>
        <div class="spinner">
            <div class="bounce1"></div>
            <div class="bounce2"></div>
            <div class="bounce3"></div>
        </div>
    </app-root>
</body>
```

chart-options in *.component.ts

```
    public barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
        datalabels: {
            display: true,
            align: 'center',
            anchor: 'center'
        }
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
};

public barChartType = 'bar';
public barChartLegend = true;
```

*.component.html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col col-sm-12">
    <div class="card mb-12">
        <div class="card-header">
            <span>
                {{ 'Production' | translate }} <small>{{ '(in pcs.)' | translate }}</small>
                <small class="summary"><i>{{ 'Summary' | translate}} <b>{{ summary }}</b></i></small>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div lang class="card-body">
            <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="dayLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Peter, did you find any solution de put these values in the middle of each section ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, @sk555. I've forgot to mark the correct answer. Sorry for this. The answer from 'user1886037' worked for me.

Comment: Hi @Peter, thanks for this comment, did you arrive to put values on the middle ? the solution below doesn't give the same result as described on the picture of the chart above. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 animation: {
  onComplete: function () {
    const chartInstance = this.chart,
      ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

    const fontSize = 20;
    const fontStyle = '600';
    const fontFamily = 'Open Sans';
    // ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(fontSize, fontStyle, fontFamily);

    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
    // ctx.fillStyle = '#676A6C';

    this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
      const meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
      meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
        if (dataset.data[index] !== 0) {
          const data = dataset.data[index].toLocaleString('it-IT', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 });
          ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 0);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did anyone arrive to put values on the middle ? the solution below doesn't give the same result as described on the picture of the chart in the question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Since ng2-charts internally uses chart.js, This can be easily achieved using a Chart.js plugin called : **[`chartjs-plugin-datalabels.`](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/options.html)**

Here is the minimum options that need to be set for this plugin to display values inside (middle) of the stacked bars :

```
options: { //your chart options
   plugins: {
      datalabels: {
         display: true,
         align: 'center',
         anchor: 'center'
      }
   }
}
```

although, there are tons of other options that you can use to further customize these values/labels (inside bars), which can be found [`here`](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/options.html).

Comment: This is what i allready tried but wont work. I've added some more code to my question